# OctoberCMS | access to static page property from component

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

There are some way to extract values from extra-fields of static pages into some component?

I need that to implement AJAX handlers...

I can load the static page content but, I need to get properties that was setted by user...

[image]

I need some example of code... I can load the static page content as a `Partial`
#noobhacks :)

```
public function onOpenHome()
{

    $this->page['categories'] = Category::all();

    return [
        //'main' => $this->renderPartial('home'),
        'main' => $this->renderPartial('../content/static-pages/index'),
        '.home_categories' => $this->renderPartial('work_list_categories_post')
    ];
}
```

or as content:

```
[viewBag]
==
<main class="home_container" __color="{{ color }}">
    <section class="box">
        {% content '/static-pages/index.htm' %} <!-- <<<<------  -->
        {{ content |raw }}
    </section>
</main>
```

But I have no ideia how to access to property of colorpicker `color`

Answer (score 2):

Component objects are available using their name (or alias). This means the value of "color" should be available via `{{ viewBag.color }}`.

Comment: Hello!
No... I can't access to it...
Unfortunately I need to leave my idea and change the projects structure....
Today I has found https://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-19
So I will follow the steps and I will implement something similar to static pages and I will make all my AJAX more easily... but thanks fot attention! Your cms is awesome!